# Python operator, no operator for "not in"

Tags: python, performance, indexing

Looking at [the mapping of operators to functions](http://docs.python.org/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions), I noticed that there is no function to express the `not in` operator.  At first I thought this was probably because the interpreter just reorders this to be `not x in y`, but there is a function for `is not` which seems like it should behave exactly the same as `not in`.  Am I missing something, or does that operator really not exist?

Here's a really stupid example where you might want this:

```
def compare_iter(a, b, func):
    return [func(aa, bb) for aa, bb in zip(a, b)]

my_compare = compare_iter(xx, yy, lambda x, y:x not in y)  # lambda -- yuck
my_compare = map(operator.not_, compare_iter(xx, yy, operator.contains)  # Extra map?  grr...
# It would be nice to do: my_compare = compare_iter(xx, yy, operator.not_contains)
```

Of course I could write my own function for this, but then you pay a price in efficiency whereas the operator module could push this code out of Python and therefore execute faster.

Comment: Indeed, couldn't `a is not b` simply be reordered to `not a is b`?

Comment: Are there situation where a check for `not in` could potentially be done faster than a check for `in`?

Comment: @PaulManta doubtful, since `not in` is by definition an exhaustive search.

Comment: @JAB -- Yes it can.  But that's not the point.  The point is that there is an asymmetry here which is a little funny.  It seems like there should be an `not_contains` function which could then be used to pass to other functions or whatever (instead of relying on `lambda`).

Comment: @ColinDunklau Not necessarily. Think about things like Bloom Filters where if but one bit is not set, you can be sure the item was not inserted into the set.

Comment: What was the **question** here? Was it "am I reading the documentation correctly?" (doesn't seem appropriate for Stack Overflow)? Was it "what predicate can I pass to `compare_iter` to get the desired result directly and efficiently?" (would need a lot of quantification)? Something else? It certainly doesn't seem like the answers here really address the *apparent* substance of the question.

Answer (score 15):

Another function is not necessary here. `not in` is the inverse of `in`, so you have the following mappings:

```
obj in seq => contains(seq, obj)

obj not in seq => not contains(seq, obj)
```

You are right this is not consistent with `is`/`is not`, since identity tests should be symmetrical. This might be a design artifact.

Comment: In thinking about this, it seems to me that another operator *should* be necessary.  `x > y` does not (necessarily) imply `not (x <= y)` in python.  Why should testing for containment be any different?

Comment: You can also use a combination of `contains` and `not_` by running `operators.not_(operators.contains(seq, obj))`. 

This is particularly useful when reading expressions from some text files. In this case, this can be used with `ops = {'in': operator.contains, 'not': operator.not_}` and calling the code as `ops['in'](seq, obj)` and `ops['not'](ops['in'](seq, obj))`

Answer (score 4):

You may find the following function and disassembly to be helpful for understanding the operators:

```
>>> def test():
        if 0 in (): pass
        if 0 not in (): pass
        if 0 is (): pass
        if 0 is not (): pass
        return None

>>> dis.dis(test)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 (())
              6 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              9 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       15
             12 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 15)

  3     >>   15 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             18 LOAD_CONST               3 (())
             21 COMPARE_OP               7 (not in)
             24 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       30
             27 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 30)

  4     >>   30 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             33 LOAD_CONST               4 (())
             36 COMPARE_OP               8 (is)
             39 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       45
             42 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 45)

  5     >>   45 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
             48 LOAD_CONST               5 (())
             51 COMPARE_OP               9 (is not)
             54 POP_JUMP_IF_FALSE       60
             57 JUMP_FORWARD             0 (to 60)

  6     >>   60 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             63 RETURN_VALUE
>>>
```

As you can see, there is a difference in each operator; and their codes (in order) are 6, 7, 8, and 9.

Comment: Yes, but if you do `not 0 in ()`, it translates it to `0 not in ()` -- This makes me think even more that there should be a corresponding operator in the operator module as `not in` is clearly a distinct (and even preferred) operator for the interpreter ...

Comment: @mgilson: Just noticed that myself. I figured it would be the other way around, but as it is I find myself agreeing with your point now. Interestingly, I can't seem to find any discussion on including `not in` as a member of `operator` in the official Python mailing lists, despite there being a discussion on the usefulness of it.

Comment: @JAB, could you post a link to some of the discussions about the usefulness? (This question was mostly academic for me, I'd love to see what other people think about actual use cases)  Is there a way to request it be added?

Comment: I guess it's more efficient to have a single bytecode for `not in` rather than first computing `in` and then computing `not`.