# Does 'not e in c' differ from 'e not in c' in Python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Order of syntax for using ‘not’ and ‘in’ keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738388/order-of-syntax-for-using-not-and-in-keywords)

My TA claims that `e not in c` doesn't always yield the same results as `not e in c` (he didn't give an explanation *why* though). I've never personally seen the second form in anyone's code (except his and books explaining that the two *are* equivalent) and never seen the two to differ in behavior so I'm suspicious of this claim. Not having found anything on it through Google I decided to come here.

So does anyone have any information about any case in which the behavior of the two differs?

Comment: There's no difference in py2k

Comment: Do you imply that there is one in Python 3.x?

Comment: I don't know about py3k. I know that there is no difference in py2k

Comment: there is 100% proof in the answer below ... take it to your TA and tell him he is wrong! ... but tell him nicely ...

Comment: There is a difference: `not e in c` yields extra confusion. If I saw it in code, I'd have to look up the operator precedence to see it wasn't `(not e) in c`.

Comment: if e is a boolean, (not e) will be flipped and that changes the meaning.

Comment: They're the same, I asked a [related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11435206/748858) a little while back.  The fact that they are the same is (in my opinion) an oversight in the specification ... Perhaps I should take it up with Guido if I ever meet him ...

Comment: @ronak: wrong. The language is designed so that both are in fact equivalent, and this takes place due to operator precedence.

Comment: see Ben's answer here -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/8738649/674039

Answer (score 26, accepted):

They are exactly same, as both actually apply the `not in` comparision:

```
In [25]: def func():
    'e' not in 'bee'
   ....:     
   ....:     

In [27]: def func1():
    not 'e' in 'bee'
   ....:     
   ....:     
In [29]: dis.dis(func)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('e')
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 ('bee')
              6 COMPARE_OP               7 (not in)
              9 POP_TOP             
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE        

In [30]: dis.dis(func1)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('e')
              3 LOAD_CONST               2 ('bee')
              6 COMPARE_OP               7 (not in)
              9 POP_TOP             
             10 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             13 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: @JanusTroelsen it's py2k

Comment: @JanusTroelsen Both, actually - on 3, you'll get the exact same outpout.

Comment: I've never used the dis module.  Wow, that was a cool application of it!

Comment: @JanusTroelsen just checked, same output on 3k.

Comment: You made exactly the same thing as Ben did here!  -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/8738649/674039

Answer (score 2):

They're identical. `not` has a lower precedence than `in`, so `not x in y` is parsed as `not (x in y)`, which returns the opposite of `in`, which is what `not in` does.

Comment: if the negation happens seperately, how come Ashwini's answer shows that it yields the same bytecode? is it in optimization?

Comment: Even explicitly adding the parens doesn't affect the bytecode generated. The block of code won't be formatted in a comment though.

Still, I believe @mipadi means how it works semantically, and not the actual implementation.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: Yeah, as pointed out, I'm showing the semantics of the code, not what's actually generated (which might be dependent on implementation details).