# What does 'is' operator do in Python?

Tags: python, operators

I was (maybe wrongfully) thinking that `is` operator is doing id() comparison.

```
>>> x = 10
>>> y = 10
>>> id(x)
1815480092
>>> id(y)
1815480092
>>> x is y
True
```

However, with `val is not None`, it seems like that it's not that simple.

```
>>> id(not None)
2001680
>>> id(None)
2053536
>>> val = 10
>>> id(val)
1815480092
>>> val is not None
True
```

Then, what does 'is' operator do? Is it just object id comparison just I conjectured? If so, `val is not None` is interpreted in Python as `not (val is None)`?

Comment: Yes, `val is not None` and `not (val is None)` are [equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941287/does-not-e-in-c-differ-from-e-not-in-c-in-python). But the first one is more readable IMO.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You missed that `is not` is an operator *too*.

Without `is`, the regular `not` operator returns a boolean:

```
>>> not None
True
```

`not None` is thus the inverse boolean 'value' of `None`. In a boolean context `None` is false:

```
>>> bool(None)
False
```

so `not None` is boolean `True`.

Both `None` and `True` are objects too, and both have a memory address (the value `id()` returns for the CPython implementation of Python):

```
>>> id(True)
4440103488
>>> id(not None)
4440103488
>>> id(None)
4440184448
```

`is` tests if two references are pointing to the *same object*; if something is the same object, it'll have the same `id()` as well. `is` returns a boolean value, `True` or `False`.

`is not` is the inverse of the `is` operator. It is the equivalent of `not (op1 is op2)`, in one operator. It should *not* be read as `op1 is (not op2)` here:

```
>>> 1 is not None     # is 1 a different object from None?
True
>>> 1 is (not None)   # is 1 the same object as True?
False
```

Comment: It is important to mention that `is not` is a single operator. `True is (not 1) -> False`, `True is not 1 -> True`. So what `not None` returns is irrelevant.

Comment: @PavelAnossov The return value of `not None` is relevant because OP used `(not None)` in one example.

Comment: @delnan: exactly, because apparently the OP missed that `is not` is a single operator. It looks like `op1 is (not None)` was expected. Which would be `False`, not `True`.

Comment: "The operators `is` and `is not` test for object identity: `x is y` is true if and only if x and y are the same object. `x is not y` yields the inverse truth value." http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/reference/expressions.html#notin

Answer (score 3):

As a complement to *Martijn Pieters* answer, `None`, `True` and `False` are singletons. There is only one instance of each of these values so it is safe to use `is` to test them..

```
>>> id(True)
8851952
>>> id(False)
8851920
>>> id(None)
8559264
>>> id(not None)
8851952
>>> id(1 == 0)
8851920
>>> id(1 == 1)
8851952
```

Comment: For `None` I agree, for `False` and `True` it might be an implementation detail. Nevertheless, testing `if xxx is True:` sounds silly to me; a mere `if xxx:` should be better.

Comment: @glglgl I agree. I just introduced `True` and `False` in the discussion as the original question mentioned `is (not None)`. That is, using the `is` operator to compare with the boolean value `(not None)` -- which is not the same as using the `is not` operator as explained in other comments.

Comment: @glglgl you can easily come up with a pathological case for `xxx is True`: returned error codes, in the manner of linux processes.  If a function succeeds, it returns True, if it fails, it returns an error code, which may be greater than 0, and hence would also evaluate to true.  Admittedly, there's far better ways of doing this, but we're being pathological here.  (Admittedly the above makes more sense to a reader than the needed `if !result:` with linux-esque zero-for-success.)

Answer (score 0):

Python tries to emulate the English language syntax to make it more human readable, but in this instance the operator precedence is a little confusing.

```
>>> val is not None
True
```

In English, we are asking if `val` does not have a value that is represented by the same object as `None`. In your above example `val=10`, so the answer is (correctly) `True`.

However, from a logical, syntactical viewpoint you have broken down the statement word-for-word and assumed it to be:

```
>>> val is (not None)
False
```

which, when enclosed in appropriate patentheses, returns your expected result (`False`).

As @Martijn Pieters points out, `is not` [is an operator in its own right](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons), and it the only operator at work here.

If you wanted to write it as a non ambiguous statement using only operators that contain no spaces, you could write:

```
>>> not (val is None)
True
```

But that is not how you would 'say' the intended statement in English, or possibly even write it in pseudo-code.