# boolean not in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean

I leaned C of the last summer from K&R book from 1989.  I am now learning python3.

I am a little confused about something.

In C if i do a test

if !(.....)   The '!' changes the value in the '( )' to the opposite, so if it was true, it becomes false and vis versa.

So what i was trying to do, is change this from C to python.

```
int card(long long number, int size){
    if(!(size == 13 || size == 15 || size == 16)) { // test to see if valid size.
        printf("INVALID\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

When i tried

```
def card(number, size):
    if !(size == 13 or size == 15 or size == 16):
        print("INVALID")
        return 0
```

I got a syntax error.

So after searching on-line I found  "is not" in the python3 doc.

so i try it on the interactive terminal.

```
   >>> if is not (size == 13 or size == 15 or size == 16):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    if is not (size == 13 or size == 15 or size == 16):
        ^
```

The interpreter was saying the 'is' is a syntax error. So i decided to remove it and see what happens. And it worked!

I searched on-line and i do not find the 'not' without the 'is'?

Is it OK to use 'if not ( ......)'  as the equivalent of 'if !(......)' in C? Or will i get into problems?  Or is there a different python way of doing this?

Comment: Just simply do `if not (...):`; In python `is` is the identity comparison operator (i.e. check whether the value assigned to a given variable is literally the same as the other).

Comment: Also that `is not` is also an operator.  Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18275616/what-does-is-operator-do-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it OK to use 'if not ( ......)' as the equivalent of 'if !(......)' in C?

Sure. Try it.

---

However, I think you're missing the `in` keyword.

You can write this

```
if(!(size == 13 || size == 15 || size == 16)) {
```

As this

```
if size not in {13, 15, 16}:
```

Comment: Never thought of using a dictionary to do the comparison. In C there is no such class similar to a dictionary. If i used an array, it would only compare the first element, unless i used a "for loop" and index to test each one item, since an array is really just a pointer to the beginning of a continues block of memory, and using it name without an index, get you to index 0.  <br/>your example worked fine.<br/> if size not in {13, 15, 16}: <br/>I thought python dictionaries where value pairs such as:  dict = {'Name': 'Zara'}  Your answer did work, but it's not value pairs, can you explain that?

Comment: It's not a dictionary, it's a set

Comment: You can also use a list. `if size not in [13, 15, 16]`

Comment: I thought { } meant dictionary.       [ ]  was a list        and   ( )  was a tuple

Comment: Thanks.  I have not seen sets yet. I am up to dictionaries in the tutorial i am taking.

Comment: I'd recommend that official tutorial rather than something like "learn python the hard way"

Answer (score 0):

"is" means two variables point  the same object,the same Memory address
U can see the link 
[Is there a difference between `==` and `is` in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python)