# Is there a way to use strip() on a list object? - python

Tags: python

For now I have an object of list like this:

```
lst = [None, None, 'one', None, 'two', None]
```

I am trying to perform strip() on it and get a result like this:

```
strip(lst)

>> ['one', None, 'two']

left_strip(lst)

>> ['one', None, 'two', None]
```

Is there a graceful way of doing that?

ps: thanks 4 @woockashek's advice, I've changed the lst
From `[None, None, 'one','two', None]` To `[None, None, 'one', None, 'two', None]`

Comment: Not a single solving attempt, just a question dump and this one has an upvote? Cool voting.

Comment: It's not clear now what you would like to achieve. What about `[None, 'one', None, 'two', None]`. You expect `['one', None, 'two']` or `['one', 'two']`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get a behaviour like `left_strip` you will need to import `dropwhile` from [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html):

```
>>> lst=[None, None, 'one', None, 'two', None, None]
>>> from itertools import dropwhile
>>> def left_strip(lst):
        return list(dropwhile(lambda x : x is None, lst))
>>> left_strip(lst)
['one',None, 'two', None, None]
```

To get a behaviour like `right_strip`:

```
>>> from itertools import dropwhile
>>> def right_strip(lst):
        return list(reversed(left_strip(reversed(lst))))
>>> right_strip(lst)
[None, None, 'one', None, 'two']
```

To get `strip` run both in sequence:

```
>>> left_strip(right_strip(lst))
['one', None, 'two']
```

Comment: Or `if item is not None` in case OP wants to keep potential zero values.

Comment: @SebastianWozny It's not a matter of "Pythonic", it simply does a different thing.

Comment: You answer for `strip` is not correct. What if You have `None` between `1` and `2`?

Comment: All concerns should be addressed now.

Answer (score 5):

You could use itertools.dropwhile to emulate an lstrip:

```
def lstrip(list):
    return list(itertools.dropwhile(lambda x : x is None, list))

lst = [None, None, 'one', 'two', None]
lstrip(lst)
>> ['one', 'two', None]
```

rstrip could be implemented in the same way, but reversing the list before 
and after using dropwhile

```
def rstrip(list):
    return list(reversed(lstrip(reversed(list))))
```

Answer (score 1):

there's a filter method:

```
lst = filter(None, lst)
```

But it  will also remove 0 values if you have them on your  list

To fix this behaviour you have to write your own filter method

```
def FilterNone(arg):
    return arg is not None

filtered_list = filter(FilterNone, lst)
```

Comment: This is not correct answer. What if You pass `lst = [None, 1, None, 2, None]`?

Comment: Example is unclear so I assumed that this situation will never occur.
I also asked about such example in OP's post but didn't get answer.

Comment: If You know what `string.strip()` does (removes empty spaces from both ends), You can assume that this is desired behavior (or course, You need to strip `None` here).

Comment: I try to read between the lines. Mentioning about `strip` doesn't guarantee that user needs its exact behaviour, that's why I'm waiting for his update.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the filter like that:

```
lst = [None, None, 'one', 'two', None]
list(filter(None.__ne__, lst))
```

Comment: This one gives `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__ne__'` on python2.7, so It's probably a python3 solution

Comment: This is not correct answer. What if You pass `lst = [None, 1, None, 2, None]`? Also, You don't have solution for `left_strip`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a natural `left_strip()`:

```
def left_strip(items):
    for i,x in enumerate(items):
        if x is not None: return items[i:]
    return [] #in case all are None
```

For example,

```
>>> left_strip(lst)
['one', 'two', None]
```

Comment: What if You pass empty list or if list contains only `None`?

Comment: @Fejs Good catch. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
def left_strip(lst):
    for i, e in enumerate(lst):
        if e is not None:
            return lst[i:]
    return []


def right_strip(lst):
    for i, e in reversed(list(enumerate(lst))):
        if e is not None:
            return lst[:i+1]
    return []

print left_strip(right_strip(lst))
```

You can read more in [remove None value from a list without removing the 0 value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096754/remove-none-value-from-a-list-without-removing-the-0-value)

Comment: First, You don't have answer for second function (`left_strip`). Second, this answer is not correct. What if You have `None` between `1` and `2`?

Answer (score 0):

Did not get what you actually want to do ? You can use lst[2:4] and lst[2:].

Update: use set

if you want to have only values which are not 'None' then you use set as shown:

```
lst = [None, None, 'one', 'two', None]
lst1=[None]
print list(set(lst)-set(lst1))
```

Comment: This answer is not correct unless You have exactly this input. Which is terrible assumption to make.

Comment: @Fejs I have indicated that it is unclear what is asked. Answer is based on the assumption of left strip.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it is:

```
def right_strip(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst) - 1, -1, -1):
        if lst[i] != None:
            break
    else:
        return []
    return lst[:i + 1]

def left_strip(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] != None:
            break
    else:
        return []
    return lst[i:]

def strip(lst):
    return left_strip(right_strip(lst))
```