# Pick the given value and ignore non-given values in a list

Tags: python, list

One of a1, a2 or a3 is given as a value while other are empty. If I want to print out only a given value, what would you like to write your code?
Thank you so much in advance.

Example,

```
a1=empty
a2=5
a3=empty
a=[a1,a2,a3]
print(a)

a=5
```

Comment: many possibilities, but maybe could use a function: `def get_value(L):
    return [x for x in L if x is not None][0]`; called with `get_value(a)`. Adapted from [remove None value from a list without removing the 0 value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16096769/1248974)

Comment: @ davewards, Thank you so much for your response. But I can't understand since I'm a newbie. Can you provide me an example code? Thank you.

Comment: no problem, sure, I'll post a demo in an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Empty values in python are `None`. So maybe something like this:

```
a1 = None
a2 = 5
a3 = None
a = [a1,a2,a3]

def get_value(L):
    return [x for x in L if x is not None][0]

a = get_value(a)

print(a)
```

output:

```
5
```

**Update**: This could fail if there is no value in the list `a`, so we should include exception handling for this case:

```
def get_value(L):
    try:
        return [x for x in L if x is not None][0]
    except IndexError:
        return None
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[e for e in a if e][0]
```

Since non-empty values are the same as True.

You could also use:

```
[a.remove(None) for e in a.count(None)]
a[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using short-circuit property:

```
print(a1 or a2 or a3)
```

Only the one different than None will be the result.

Comment: Right, but this will return a boolean, and he wants the actual value