# How to convert list of list of word strings to strings as sentences?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have tried ways on converting list to strings as found in other questions but the output doesn't seem to be what I should get. I have an input of `[['This','is','here.'],['Second','sentence','here.']]` and I would like to convert this to string and be saved to a text file with the output:

```
This is here.
Second sentence here.
```

what I did is,

```
list = [['This','is','here.'],['Second','sentence','here.']]
with open(outfile, 'w') as newfile:
    newfile.write(str('\n'.join((str(i) for i in list))))
```

The output of this in the .txt file is:

```
['This', 'is', 'here.']
['Second', 'sentence', 'here.']
```

A help is very much appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Notice that you have a list of lists. You also need to use `join()` on the inner lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `lst = '\n'.join(' '.join(i) for i in txt)` (*Also, it is good 
 to use variable name other than* `list`):

```
txt = [['This','is','here.'],['Second','sentence','here.']]
with open(outfile, 'w') as newfile:
    lst = '\n'.join(' '.join(i) for i in txt)
    newfile.write(lst)
```

## Update:

Looks like the the item in list has `None`, you can filter them as explained in [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16097112/5916727) and use following:

```
txt = [['This','is','here.'],['Second','sentence','here.'], ['Here',None, 'is']]
lst = '\n'.join(' '.join(list(filter(None.__ne__, i))) for i in txt)
print(lst)
```

Result:

```
This is here.
Second sentence here.
Here is
```

As suggested in comments below, just adding additional timing results for comparing `filter` to `list comprehension` in this case, and `list comprehension` is faster:

```
%%timeit
txt = [['This','is','here.'],['Second','sentence','here.'], ['Here',None, 'is']]
lst = '\n'.join(' '.join(list(filter(None.__ne__, i))) for i in txt)

# Result: 100000 loops, best of 3: 4.52 µs per loop
```

---

```
%%timeit
txt = [['This','is','here.'],['Second','sentence','here.'], ['Here',None, 'is']]
lst = '\n'.join(' '.join(([j for j in i if j != None])) for i in txt)

# Result: 100000 loops, best of 3: 3.28 µs per loop
```

Comment: Side question... Let's say I wanted to give a right/left pad between the words, how can I achieve it?

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand the question, what is the expected output in above text?

Comment: I had the error when I tried it: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found @student

Comment: @student the expected output are two sentences where the second sentence is on the next line.

Comment: @student I'm not OP, sorry about that. I just have the same list comprehension but I want my output to be like a table (hence the padding)

Comment: @student yeah you're right there is None in my actual list. sorry about the sample text. It worked! Thanks for the help!

Comment: `Happy Coding`. @Tico I am not sure but if you have question posted I can try to help.

Comment: @student Nice -- the `filter(None.__ne__, i)` part is really interesting, are there any advantages / differences to just doing e.g. a list comprehension with `if i`? Thanks!

Comment: @patrick Thanks for the comment. I added the results from timing, `list comprehension` is better as usual I think.

Comment: @Tico If I understand your question correctly, [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/) might be what you are looking for

Comment: @student Yeah, but I was having trouble placing the function at the right place. I end up adding a `ljust()` while `push`ing the items to my list

Comment: @Tico may be you can create `dataframe` using `pandas` and print it as table?

Comment: @student it's just a small project for some friends, but that's a good idea

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.join` to convert list to strings

```
>>> l=[['This','is','here.'],['Second','sentence','here.']]
>>> print ('\n'.join([' '.join(e) for e in l]))
This is here.
Second sentence here.
>>>
```

Comment: i tried this but it resulted to an error:  TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, NoneType found