# What is the purpose of doing my_list = list(filter(None, my_list))

Tags: python, filter

I've seen the following line in a piece of code I'm reading and I just don't understand its purpose:

```
my_list = list(filter(None, my_list))
```

`my_list` is just a list of words. Why would someone choose to do this? It seems to me like all this does it return the list as is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [remove None value from a list without removing the 0 value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16096754/remove-none-value-from-a-list-without-removing-the-0-value)

Comment: it's not clear to me how that link answers this question. The OP is not asking how to remove `None` without removing zeros. The code in the question removes both and any other falsy values.

Comment: The question in the link has the exact syntax, which tells that it is used to remove the None and 0 [ FALSE ]. is is not what you are looking for ?

Comment: @roshanok the OP in that question is using this formulation and *not* getting the result they want. None of the answers actually addresses what this does, which is *this* OP's question. It doesn't actually answer *this* question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This will filter out [falsy](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) values from `my_list` and return a new list. It's probably best illustrated with an example:

```
my_list = [1, 2 , 0, 3, None, 4, False, True, [], [1], '', 'abc']

list(filter(None, my_list))
# [1, 2, 3, 4, True, [1], 'abc']
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) explains it:

> **filter(function, iterable)**
> ...
> If function is None, the identity function is assumed, that is, all elements of iterable that are false are removed.

Comment: Bah... you link and quote the documentation saying "false" and still say "falsy" instead. Wish people would stop using such made-up words and just use the official Python terminology :-)

Comment: All words are made up @HeapOverflow, but point taken, “falsy” does not seem to be used in python docs. One windmill defeated…now we can adjust our *falsies* and move on.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. But yeah, I think the Python docs consistently use "true" and "false" (without any styling).