# Why Python need rich comparison?

Tags: python

There is a confusion for me for some time: is there a scene that we do need to use rich comparison in Python?

I read the official doc [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__), but it only gives how it works not why we need it.

A snippet of the doc:

> *The truth of `x==y` does not imply that `x!=y` is false.* may describe a scene that we need rich comparison. In this scene, we can
>   make `__eq__` and `__ne__` both return `False` for disabling the
>   comparsion or any other purpose. (We can implement this by using
>   `__cmp__`)

But this just a guess, I have never encountered such a requirement in a real project yet.

Does anyone need to use rich comparison indeed or is there any other scenario where we need to use rich comparison in theory?

Maybe my example of `x==y` and `x!=y` caused some confusion, sorry for that.
Let me make it a bit clearer:
Are there any scenario where rich comparison can help but `__cmp__` can not?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question... but say for example, you want to compare a custom class object against another object of the same class. For that you need to define the so called "rich comparison" operators.

Comment: I don't understand how returning `false` on both `==` and `!=` results in "disabling comparison". It is enabled and gives counter-intuitive results. If I wanted to disabled it I would fire up an exception. I kind of look at it as the "rule of three" in `c++` operators are not disable if you make them do nonsense. You got to hide/protect/delete them.

Comment: @ikaros45: The OP wants to know in what scenario you'd make `__eq__` and `__ne__` return `False` for the same other object.

Comment: @ikaros45 For that, I can define `__cmp__`. Actually I want to know whether there is a scene that rich comparison can help, but `__cmp__` can't?

Comment: In 2 years of working with Python full-time, I have never needed to define `__ne__` in a way other than `x != y`. No motivation is given for allowing `x==y` not to imply that `x!=y` in the corresponding [PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0207/). I personally think `not (x == y)` should be the default implementation for `__ne__`.

Comment: [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/). Further explanation to follow...

Comment: @luk32 Sorry for the inproper discription "disabling comparsion", it means a scene that you don't want the comparison return `True`.

Comment: Lovely opinion, but this is not an answer to the question, is it? I've worked with Python for 15 years, and I've not had much occasion to do this either, but I've worked with projects that do interesting stuff with rich comparisons nonetheless, and no such default should or can be made, as `__eq__` can return something other than a boolean.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) uses rich comparisons to vectorize `==`, `!=`, `<`, etc, just like it does with most other operators. For example,

```
>>> x = numpy.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
>>> y = numpy.array([2, 2, 1, 4, 4])
>>> x == y
array([False,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

When arrays `x` and `y` are compared with any comparison operator, NumPy applies the operator (roughly) elementwise and returns an array of results. This is useful, for example, to apply an operation to the cells of `x` that fit the condition:

```
>>> x[x==y] = 6
>>> x
array([1, 6, 3, 6, 5])
```

Here, I've selected all elements of `x` that equal the corresponding elements of `y`, and set them equal to 6.

Comment: An very good example, that's what I want. But a further question: does python design rich comparison for similar purpose? Or NumPy find it as a smart way to use it like this?

Comment: @WKPlus: This is specifically the primary reason rich comparisons were added to the language. To quote [PEP 207](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0207/): "The main motivation comes from NumPy, whose users agree that A<B should return an array of elementwise comparison outcomes; they currently have to spell this as less(A,B) because A<B can only return a Boolean result or raise an exception."

Answer (score 9):

You don't even need to return boolean values. The point the documentation is making is that you are given total freedom over what the overloaded methods can return; Python does not *enforce* that `__eq__` and `__ne__` return consistent boolean values.

The [SQLAlchemy project](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) has overloaded the rich comparison operators altogether to return something else entirely. If you use:

```
model1.column == model2.column
```

or

```
model1.column != model2.column
```

or

```
model1.column < model2.column
```

where `model1` and `model2` are both SQLAlchemy table models then you don't get a boolean value, what you get is a *SQL query filter* instead.

You use the return values to construct SQL queries:

```
model1.filter(model1.column <= model2.column)
```

would result in a SQL query along the lines of:

```
select model1.*
from model1
left join model2 on model1.foreign_key == model2.primary_key
where
    model1.column <= model2.column
```

entirely in Python code, using Python rich comparison syntax.

Comment: google app engine and I believe Django do the same thing with query filters in a very analogous way.  I have no idea who did it first (but I don't think it was GAE)...

Comment: @mgilson: the concept has been around for a long, long time. SQLAlchemy predates both Django and GAE, but I don't think it was the first project to use it. Numpy uses similar techniques, I think it might be older than SQLAlchemy.

Comment: Nice post. A further question: does python design rich comparison for similar purpose? Or SQLAIchemy and other projects find it as a smart way to use it like this?

Comment: @WKPlus: It is part of the Python philosophy to not dictate too strictly what special methods should and should not accept and return.

Comment: Thanks, the explanation in PEP 207 is what I need. Thanks for the example.

Comment: @mgilson: aaaaand... I was sorta wrong. It's only been around since 2007 and at Numpy kicked off the [PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0207/) for it.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- They do seem pretty set on having `__contains__` return a boolean value though -- which I never quite understood...

Comment: @mgilson: what would the `not in` operator return if `__contains__` returns anything other than a boolean? There is no `__notcontains__` hook.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I know.  At one point, [I asked for one](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/1055307?do=post_view_flat#1055307) and was told pretty much that it was a stupid idea :).  Actually, all I really wanted was [`operator.not_in`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11435206/748858) to be added ... having a `__notcontains__` hook was a corollary.